# Task Thread Context Switches

Tags: .net, multithreading, task, context-switch

I was reading around and read that if I use Tasks instead of Threads in .Net they would not be susceptible to Context Switches that Threads have issues with.

However reading around I also noticed that Tasks just use Threads under the covers anyway.

So I am a bit confused, any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should post the URL you found that gave you the wrong information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you've read is wrong.

`Task` is part of the TPL. The TPL uses a more advanced scheduler, than the CLR's threadpool. An example is that the TPL scheduler uses [`WorkStealingQueues`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0.aspx).

**A few facts:**

- Whether you do `Task.Factory.StartNew`, or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, both will use the same threadpool (.NET 4.0)
- Whether you use a `Task` or "raw" Threads, each timeslice will cause a context switch.
- Also if a higher priority thread becomes runnable it will cause a context switch.
- A `Task` will cause just as many context switches as a regular thread.

Note that a context switch, only occurs if there aren't enough processors to handle the threads simultaneously.

**Some links to check out:**

- *Difference between TPL and Threadpool, and the change threadpool in .NET 4.0:
  http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx*
- *Shows how to implement a WorkStealingQueue in C#:
  http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/08/12/BuildingACustomThreadPoolSeriesPart2AWorkStealingQueue.aspx*
- *A short version of daniel moth's blog post:
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0.aspx*

Answer (score 1):

Context switches are not inherent in threads, they're inherent in misuse of threads. Tasks use threads in such a way that whatever thread happens to be running can take whatever task needs to be done, avoiding the expensive context switches that occur when threads are misused.

Comment: "Context switches are not inherent in threads"? The world has changed since I was young.

Comment: No, they're not. If you have four ready-to-run threads and four cores, each core can run the same thread for the same amount of time it could run a process. The only time you get an extra context switch with threads is when the thread that happens to be running can't do any more work even though there's more work to do. If that happens, it's because your code created that situation. (Tasks avoid it by letting the thread that's already running do whatever work needs to be done.)

Comment: Or, perhaps, when the OS decides it wants to do something else instead of run your four threads?

Comment: Sure, but that context switch has nothing to do with multithreading. It would occur the same way if there were four different processes running.

Comment: Threads are the _only_ things that context-switch. The threads _within_ a process may context-switch, but the process does not. And where did processes enter the discussion? The question is about threads and tasks.

Comment: I don't know if you're deliberately trying to misunderstand me, but the context of the question is multithreading and whether that results in additional context switches. I think you're deliberately taking my first sentence in isolation and ignoring the fact that it's a response to the question and is further clarified in the immediately following sentences.

Comment: "I was reading around and read that if I use Tasks instead of Threads in .Net they would not be susceptible to Context Switches that Threads have issues with." Did you think when he said "Tasks" that he meant "processes"? He's asking about two different multithreading techniques in .NET, not about multithreading vs. not multithreading.

Comment: I understand that. That's why I wrote, "Tasks use threads in such a way that whatever thread happens to be running can take whatever task needs to be done, avoiding the expensive context switches that occur when threads are misused."

Comment: Ok, I get you now. You need badly to clarify. You mean that there are no context switches inherent in the process of switching between tasks. You do not mean that the operating system never preempts a thread. Of course, preemption is inherent in threads, but one can avoid context switches when switching from one piece of work to another by using Tasks to encapsulate that work instead of raw threads.

Comment: Pre-emption is not inherent in threads, it's inherent in a pre-emptive, multi-tasking OS. Nothing about using threads requires any pre-emption that wouldn't happen otherwise.

Comment: With respect, is there any operating system that anybody cares about, which does not use preemption? Your statement is a bit academic.

Comment: "The only time you get an extra context switch with threads is when the thread that happens to be running can't do any more work even though there's more work to do." Sorry I dont understand this, Can you please clarify, of course if you write code and your thread has no more work to do then you kill it?

Comment: @AllenHo I'm not sure how I can make it clearer than I already have. If a thread is running and there's no work left to do, a context switch is mandatory, if for no other reason, to switch to the system's idle process. If a thread is running and there is more work left to do, and that thread can do the work, then there will be no extra context switch -- the thread will do whatever work it has to do next. The only time you get an *extra* context switch is when a thread finishes doing some work, there's more work to do, and **that** thread cannot do it. (So you switch to the thread that can.)

Comment: @JohnSaunders I didn't bring up pre-emption. But in any event, it's irrelevant. Unless the people who designed your OS are idiots (and they're not), they'd only let one thing pre-empt another if that was beneficial. So complaining about context switches due to pre-emption is silly -- they improve performance. The only issue here is *bad* context switches. (In fact, another advantage of threads is that they facilitate pre-emption, allowing context switches where they are beneficial.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: perhaps operating systems have changed since I was young, and nobody bothered to tell me. "Back in the day", a context switch would occur whenever there were more threads in Ready state than there were CPUs to run them. In that case, each Ready thread would be allowed to execute for a "quantum" period, after which there was a context switch to another Ready thread. Perhaps fairness was considered "beneficial".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Right, but those context switches aren't necessary. They're implemented intentionally by the operating system because they make things *better*. To complain about good context switches is irrational and to try to minimize them is suicidal. The issue is *bad* context switches, which only occur under the circumstances that I explained. (When there's work that needs to be done but the currently executing thread *can't* make any forward progress, *requiring* a context switch to allow the system to make forward progress even if the context switch would be harmful.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: _not necessary_? Make it _better_? They make it _possible_!

Comment: @JohnSaunders Correct, they're not necessary. The system as a whole can continue to make forward progress without them. But in any event, they're **good** context switches. You wouldn't want to avoid or minimize them. The issue here is *bad* context switches that make things worse, so this is an irrelevancy.

Comment: Glad to see that they both stopped going at each other!! You guys need each other's number?